# how to target the <li> item using jquery and change its text

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I'm trying to change the  "li" item in group of "li" items. I'm having a hell of a time trying to get to it and change its' text can anyone point me in the right direction.
i have tried the following

```
 $("#chosen-results" ).find("li").text("hide trip history");
```

i know that this wont work because i need to get more specific but this is where I'm stuck.
Thanks in advance.

**update**
  I apologgize to everyone who answered the question
  this is not the last item in the dropdown sorry for the misguidance. this is really just an item in a  list of many "li"
Miguel

Comment: The answer you seek [was in the documentation all along](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Comment: I was about to point out that the first criteria for a downvote is _this question does not show any research effort_, which is absolutely valid. Now that you've edited your question, it is unclear how to solve your problem. Relax, it's not personal. My interest is only in maintaining the quality of questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the eq filter in selecter to filter specific.

```
   //sets for all.
 $("#chosen-results" ).find("li").text("hide trip history");



//sets for  the second result  //0 based
 $("#chosen-results" ).find("li").eq(1).text("hide trip history");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`:last Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/):

---

**CODE:**

```
$("#chosen-results").find("li:last").text("hide trip history");
```

---

**DEMO:**

- [**A SIMPLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CVnxy/)

---

Comment: what if i wanted to find it within a list and its not the last one in the list of items?

Comment: @Miguel: Then you can use the [`:eq() Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) for that... [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CVnxy/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul.chosen-results li:last').text("hide trip history");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('ul.chosen-results li.active-result.group-option').text('hide trip history');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("ul.chosen-results" ).find("li").last().text("hide trip history");
```

or

```
$("ul.chosen-results" ).find("li:last").text("hide trip history");
```

References

http://api.jquery.com/find/

http://api.jquery.com/last/

http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#chosen-results li:last").text("hide trip history");
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hHwuV/

Answer (score 1):

First off, you probably want to read up on CSS selectors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors
http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/

Now, your `ul` element has a **class** of `chosen-results` not an id, so you need to start with `$('.chosen-results')`. Then you want the last `li` within that so you can use the `:last-child` selector with `.find()`:

```
$(".chosen-results" ).find("li:last-child").text("hide trip history");
```

But note that this will affect all the `li` elements that are the last child of it's parent's, and are located with an element with class `chosen-results`. If there are multiple such elements, and you only want one, then you'll need to get more specific with the selectors, or maybe add in an extra class or id to your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/):

```
$( "li" ).last().text("The new text");
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64ezU/) for a demonstration. You could also use the `:last` selector:

```
$( "li:last ").text("The new text");
```

You may also consider checking out the documentation on [traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).